# How does Hyperledger Fabric handle partial committer failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I read the Hyperledger Fabric documentation, it says that after orderer validates a transaction, it will broadcast the transaction to all submitter peers;

And committer will continue validate the transaction, like verify the readset to make sure it is not changed in state db.

My question is what Fabric should do when readset validating is failed in partial submitter peers.

As we know, previously, the proposal process has succeed, and orderer service also has passed the transaction validation, and rest of the submitters have also validated the transaction and write transaction data into ledger.

Under this circumstance, how Hyperledger Fabric handle this case?

1. abort this transaction ? but other submitters have written into the ledge.
2. continue this transaction ? but some submitters cannot pass the validation because of readset is changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this cannot happen. Either the *all* of the validating peers will validate or fail the transaction. In the case that the validation fails, neither the statedb nor ledger will be updated with the transaction on any of them. The transaction will remain in the block, but an event will be published indicating that the transaction failed and should be resubmitted.

Comment: Make sense, if that happen,the whole fabric storage must be in chaos, thank you; another question, if in the case validation fails, how many failure events client would receive ? if there are more than one committer, will each publish a failure event to client ?

Comment: I believe that each peer sends an event since they are unaware of the others. Note also that peers also stay current by gossiping amongst themselves.